# How do high-DPI devices like Retina displays and 1080p phones handle pixels in media queries?

Tags: html, css, media-queries, screen-resolution, dpi

For example, how many pixels does the iPhone with a Retina display appear to a media query? Is it 320 pixels or 640 pixels? If it's 640 pixels, how can a website deal with different device resolutions? Is there any way to use units that are the same regardless of a screen's resolution?

Comment: [CSS Pixels are not physical pixels](http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2010/04/a_pixel_is_not.html)

Comment: That's interesting... At least it's one less thing to worry about when it comes to CSS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Retina devices like the iPhone and iPad usually use 2 device pixels = 1 CSS pixel. So a media query like this:

```
@media all and (max-width: 320px) {
}
```

actually will target an iPhone (portrait), even though it is 640 device pixels wide.

Comment: iPhone wasn't *always* a Retina device, but yes, this will target iPhone in portrait regardless of its display resolution. In fact, if anything the fact that there exist both Retina and non-Retina iPhones is what makes CSS pixels so powerful.